# Photoshop: how to align multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, alignment

I need 3 circles aligned straight. I draw a circle using Ellipse tool. When I draw a second circle, I either draw it in the same layer or I draw it in a new layer.

The problem I am facing when I draw the circle in a same layer. I make a change to one circle, that change is also applied to the other circle (I don't want this). However, I can align the circles in a straight line.

If I draw the second circle on a new layer, I can make changes to both circles separately, however, now I cannot align these circles on a straight line, align option is grayed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *want* a separate layer.

Highlight **both** layers in the Layers Panel by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and clicking the layers. Then the align buttons will be available.

If you only have one layer highlighted, there's nothing to align *to* so the buttons will be disabled. You can't align a single layer to itself.

Comment: Thank you Scott! This helped. I was highlighting both layers, however, the alignment option was still grayed out. I learnt that there are two alignment options, one is path alignment, this is the one I was using to align multiple layers and it obviously won't work. In layers, there is layer alignment options which worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question. Please see Scott’s answer. If you want different colours or styling, you probably want two separate layers (there’s ways to get a single layer with different styling, but that’s a more complex solution).

It is possible to align shape objects within a single Photoshop layer.

The secret is having the `Path Selection` tool *and* the objects you’d like to align selected (if both those conditions aren’t met, the option to align objects will not be available).

[image: Path selection tool]

The align options are now available, and they work within the layer(s) and object(s) selected.

[image: Align objects]

And, the end result…

[image: Aligned objects in Photoshop]

Comment: The question states that as a single layer the issue is *different appearances are needed*, not that the alignment doesn't work.

Comment: Apologies for misreading it. I have up-voted your answer.